# React: Styling SVG images as React components in TypeScript using SCSS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg, webpack, sass

I'm using Webpack to allow importing SVG files as components in React Typescript. I'm having issues styling the SVGs using SCSS. I'm using a made-up attribute as a target for the css selector, but no properties within that class are being applied to the SVG 'component'.

**Code example of SVG usage as a component:**

```
import GitHubLogo from './github.svg';

...

return (
  <div>
    <GitHubLogo social-icon />
  </div>
)
```

**The CSS selector for the component would be:**

```
[social-icon] {
    ...
}
```

**An example SVG could be:**

```
<svg width="48px" height="48px" fill="#ffffff">
    <rect width="10px" height="10px"></rect>
</svg>
```

**Webpack module rule for handling SVG files (if that's the issue):**

```
{
  test: /\.svg$/i,
  issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
  resourceQuery: { not: [/url/] },
  use: ['@svgr/webpack']
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with what props get passed down to this React SVG component, but you may be to just add a `className='social-icon'` as a prop and check if it is assigned to the SVG element in the DOM. If so, then you can just target that class name. If not, you can make your own React SVG component and accept certain props.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the custom attribute you're using ("social-icon") is not being recognized as a valid attribute in the SVG. You can use the "className" property to apply a CSS class to the SVG element, and then use a traditional CSS class selector to style the SVG.

```
import GitHubLogo from './github.svg';

...

return (
  <div>
    <GitHubLogo className="social-icon" />
  </div>
)
```

In your CSS file;

```
.social-icon {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  fill: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: My first thought. The issue is since it's not a recognized React type, traditional element attributes aren't available...

Comment: Thanks for your comment - it made me realize React was giving me some console errors regarding the custom attribute, so I just followed the hint. All working now.